# VBA UserForm Frame ScrollTop function not working from class function

Tags: excel, vba, class, scrolltop

This should be a simple task and I've been coding in VBA for 10+ years but I cannot seem to get this to work.  I have a UserForm with a MultiPage (with 2 pages).  I am just working on the first page (Pages(0)), which has a Frame on it.  just outside the frame are dynamically added labels (A - Z) and I have made a class to handle the onclick WithEvents.  When the label is clicked I want the Frame to 'ScrollTop' to the corresponding name that starts with that letter.  Inside the frame is many checkboxes with users names.

Here is what the form looks like.

[image: Frame with vertical scroll]

Here is the class event handler when the user clicked a label (Letter A - Z)

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents LetterClick   As MSForms.Label 'A - Z Letters on report output userform (to scroll the frame down to the declarant name start letter)

Dim Ctrl    As Control

Private Sub LetterClick_Click()

    With form_report_output_menu.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Frame1
    
        For Each Ctrl In .Controls
            
            If TypeName(Ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
                Debug.Print Ctrl.Caption
                If Mid(Ctrl.Caption, 1, 1) = LetterClick.Caption Then
                    .ScrollTop = Ctrl.Top: Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next Ctrl
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it currently doing? I did a test using your code and worked as expected. Top of the scroll went to first item that matched.

Comment: Hi @Simon and thanks for your comment.  That's odd as my code simply does nothing to scroll the frame.  In debug mode when the line hits to ScrollTop the scrollbars do not move.  I therefore think it must be something to do with the fact that the checkboxes inside the Frame are dynamically added when the userform is initialized.

Comment: You could test that theory by just manually putting a checkbox in there in the designer and loading. I would also try a test setting a straight value for the `.ScrollTop` instead of `Ctrl.Top` to rule that out as well. I did an attempt just now dynamically adding checkboxes in the initialize event and it still worked to them. Seems strange why that isn't working. I can only think something is conflicting with it.